# how does the inside of "if (console.clear)" evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, console

I'm using some code to skip clearing the console in Safari, because this function is not defined in Safari

```
if (console.clear) { console.clear() };
```

But how does "console.clear" ever evaluate to true? The outputs don't look anything like true.

```
console.log(console.clear);

// undefined                                Safari
// function()                               FF
// function clear() { [native code] }       Opera, Chrome, IE
```

Comment: console.clear without parentheses returns a function object, which is *truthy*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if target is not one of these, it returns true in if statement:

```
'', (+-)0, null, undefined, NaN, false
```

Comment: -0 and NaN are also falsy. Oh, and false itself. ;)

Comment: you forgot boolean `false`

Answer (score 4):

All objects are considered truthy, and functions are objects in JavaScript. If the function is not defined, it will return undefined, which is falsy.

One more thing: your code will throw an error if `console` itself doesn't exist (which is the case in IE<=9 without dev tools open). A safer test would be:

```
if (console && console.clear) { console.clear() };
```